# MapProxy not reprojecting TMS before 1:35M

Tags: mapproxy

I have some TMS layers in MapProxy that I reproject from GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR to GLOBAL_GEODETIC as follow (all of them using same configuration so I'll show only one):

Source:

```
  opentopomaps_tms:
    type: tile
    grid: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR
    url: https://b.tile.opentopomap.org/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.png
    transparent: true
    request_format: image/png
    concurrent_requests: 5
    http:
      client_timeout: 600
```

Cache:

```
  opentopomaps_cache:
    grids: [GLOBAL_GEODETIC]
    sources: [opentopomaps_cache_in]
    disable_storage: false
    link_single_color_images: true
    concurrent_tile_creators: 4
    format: image/png

  opentopomaps_cache_in:
    grids: [GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR]
    sources: [opentopomaps_tms]
    disable_storage: true
    link_single_color_images: true
    concurrent_tile_creators: 4
    format: image/png
```

Layer:

```
  - name: opentopomaps
    title: OpenTopoMaps
    sources: [opentopomaps_cache]
```

My problem is: when I'm before scale 1:35M the map seems not reprojected. Here are some examples in 1:70M:

[image]

[image]

And when I go further to 1:35M the map is like I expect:

[image]

[image]

Is that the correct behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well... Seems some cache from my old configuration. After cleaned the cache from zoom level 00 to 04 all works fine.

Go to /mapproxy/cache_data/ and do this:

```
rm -rf opentopomaps_cache_EPSG4326/00
rm -rf opentopomaps_cache_EPSG4326/01
rm -rf opentopomaps_cache_EPSG4326/02
rm -rf opentopomaps_cache_EPSG4326/03
rm -rf opentopomaps_cache_EPSG4326/04
```

Done!